# Cassandra: Data Type for Partition Key - Decimal or UUID

Tags: cassandra

I want to describe the problem I am working on first:
Currently I try to find a strategy that would allow me to migrate data from an existing PostgreSQL database into a Cassandra cluster. The primary key in the PostgreSQL is a decimal value with 25 digits. When I migrate the data, it would be nice if I could keep the value of the current primary key in one way or another and use it to uniquely identify the data in Cassandra. This key should be used as the partition key in Cassandra (no other columns are involved in the table I am talking about). After doing some research, I found out that a good practise is to use UUIDs in Cassandra. So now I have two possible solutions to solve my problem:

1. I can either create a transformation rule, that would transfer my current decimal primary keys from the PostgrSQL database into UUIDs for Cassandra. Everytime someone requests to access some of the old data, I would have to reapply the transformation rule to the key and use the UUID to search for the data in Cassandra. The transformation would happen in an application server, that manages all communication with Cassandra (so no client will talk to Cassandra directly) New data added to Cassandra would of course be stored with an UUID.
2. The other solution, which I already have implemented in Java at the moment, is to use a decimal value as the partition key in Cassandra. Since it is possible, that multiple application servers will talk to Cassandra concurrently, my current approach is to generate a UUID in my application and transform it into a decimal value. Using this approach, I could simply reuse all the existing primary keys form PostgreSQL.

I cannot simply create new keys for the existing data, since other applications have stored their own references to the old primary key values and will therefore try to request data with those keys.

Now here is my question: Both approaches seem to work and end up with unique keys to identify my data. The distribution of data across all node should also be fine. But I wonder, if there is any benefit in using a UUID over a decimal value as partition key or visa versa. I don't know exactly what Cassandra does to determine the hash value of the partition key and therefore cannot determine if any data type is to be preferred. I am using the Murmur3Partitioner for Cassandra if that is relevant.

Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two benefits of UUID's that I know of.

First, they can be generated independently with little chance of collisions.  This is very useful in distributed systems since you often have multiple clients wanting to insert data with unique keys.  In RDBMS we had the luxury of auto-incrementing fields to give uniqueness since that could easily be done atomically, but in a distributed database we don't have efficient global atomic locks to do that.

The second advantage is that UUID's are fairly efficient in terms of storage, and only require eight bytes.

As long as your old decimal values are unique, you should be able to use them as partition keys.

Comment: I am aware of the benefit that they can be generated with little chance of collision (at least for a few hundret years). But since I have a transformation rule that transforms UUIDs into 25-digit decimal values, I should not lose this benefit. The transformation will take every byte of the UUID into account, so no information is lost and the uniqueness is still save. Are you sure UUIDs only require 8 bytes for storing them? As far as I know, UUIDs are 128 bit (16 byte) values. Therefore I don't see why they would require less bytes to store them.

Comment: I think you're right.  UUID's look like they use 16 bytes.  I might have been thinking of timestamps, which are 8 bytes.